# Receive .ajax in PHP without form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got this script:

```
<script>
var request;
$("#foo").click(function(event){
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/votesHandler.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "true"
        });
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert("Voted!");
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(
                "Oops, something went wrong"
            );
        });
        request.always(function () {
            alert("Done.");
        });
</script>
```

And what I'm trying to do is send "true" to the server when the #foo element is clicked. I've used AJAX only a few times before and each time it was with forms. The problem is that I need to receive this POST request in PHP (with `$_POST['foo']`) but this time the input is not the name of a text input. How do I send `data` into `$_POST` without a form?

Comment: Please go back to the question I answered a few days ago and tell me whether it solved your problem.

Comment: Couldn't find it but another answer did. And yeah I also checked the answer on my other question (sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the key of data when you send to your url.

```
$.ajax({
 data: {foo: 'true'}
});
```

To retrieve it use

```
$_POST['foo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Send it as:

```
data: 'foo_clicked=1',
```

or

```
data: 'foo_clicked=' + somevarname,
```

On the PHP side:

```
$recd = $_POST['foo_clicked'];
if ($recd == 1) {
     //do what you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $("#form").submit(function (e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    console.log(formURL); //your form action
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        beforeSend: function () {
           //do
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('success data');
            //whatever

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //if fails
            console.log('fail');
        }

    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});
```